# Best plan about delta migration

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, migration, data-migration, delta-migration

- Three months before I migrated **Magento 1.9.3.3CE** to **Magento 2.1.7EE**
- I added/update CMS content.
- Install 20+ extensions and configured all.
- For testing, I altered some of the products, orders, customers of the current M2 database. [Major stuck point]
- For testing I added products, customers, orders..etc

I'm planning for **delta migration** but I have some doubts

- is delta migration overwrite whatever products we altered?
- If M1 admin altered product, those details got reflected in M2 while delta Migration?

I'm looking for proper/best planning about delta migration. Also, I would like to know **Do's** and **Don't Do's** while delta migration.

Comment: Customers adding themself to M1 or changing their addresses (while not touching customers in M2) is not supported with delta migration?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140061)

Comment: How did your plan after migrating data update? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/316626/57334 @Bilal Usean Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here are some **Delta migration General understanding**

Data Migration Tool migrates data created only by Magento's own modules (*eg. 
 Orders, Customers Profile*) and is not responsible for the code or extensions made by third-party developers.

If these extensions created data in the frontend database and the merchant wants to have this data in Magento 2, then config files of the Data Migration Tool should be created and modified accordingly.

After main Data Migration, Data added to the Magento 1 database (eg. Data added by customer on frontend). To migrate these data in Magento 2, This Delta tool will Database triggers for tables.

Changes may include revisions to your Product Categories, Products themselves --again, the Deltas do track changes in inventory, so excluding that. Not recommend to deleting products that were migrated, as the delta may blow up when attempting to update the inventory for deleted product(s) -- CMS Pages, Static Blocks.

The deltas, do not track every change on the M1 database. For example you can go ahead and make all the changes you like to store configuration, as there is no Deltas for that.

So, While we do incremental Migrations, its enables you to migrate only the changes made in Magento 1 since the last time you migrated data. These changes are:

- Data that customers added via storefront (created orders, reviews,
  changes in customer profiles, etc.)
- All operations with orders in the
  Magento Admin panel
- Catalog Inventory Stock changes.

**Important!**

Not recommend doing any of the following on your M2 database after your initial migration if you plan to run Deltas with it's default configuration:

- Add/Remove products (on either DB. If you do add the product to both databases at the same time in the same order so that their entity_id on both databases match, this is only for inventory reasons, not attribute information reasons)
- Add/Remove customers
- Create any new orders
- Attempt to manage product inventory

Comment: thanks for sharing +1. I'm waiting for others response too. I'm looking flow of plan like this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-plan.html but I thought this is not a complete guide to migrate efficiently. The client only gives 4-8hrs for migration from M1 to M2. After migration, I want to keep theme customization, extension configuration, cms content as well as keep M1 and M2 records both are same. If you read my question, you realize I need to do it again from the scratch for the correct records. I'm really concern about how to avoid this unnecessary repeated work.

Comment: It is wrong estimated for only 4-8hours. To my mind, You will face on many issues and you have to create or extend the tool to migrate the custom data.

Comment: 4-8 hours means for maintenance mode enabling time :-), not for whole project completion. @FranckGarnier

Comment: Still, I don't get a clear idea about the effective way of migration, anyway I accepted, If you found anything regarding this, please keep update your answer. thanks @Irfan

Comment: Hello,I have Migrated My data 2 month before while my M1 database and M2 both DB name has been changed so what will require to run command for delta process?If I change my config.xml file then is require to run command     php bin/magento migrate:settings --auto /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.1.0/config.xml  ?

Comment: @Irfan Momin, we have migrated M1 to M2 database successfully we would like to migrate delta what exact commend we have used? please advise ASAP.

Comment: Do you recommend using delta migration or something like this with a copy of M1 database: https://www.czettner.com/2018/09/13/magento-2-data-migration.html

Comment: "Not recommend doing any of the following on your M2 database after your initial migration if you plan to run Deltas with it's default configuration"

WHY not?