# Magento 2.3 - How to update Migrated Data?

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3.4, data-migration

I already migrated Magento 1 data to Magento 2.3.4, during development we got few orders placed in Magento 1 as well as new customers registered in Magento 1. How to update the migration data i mean how to sync as per date data to Magento 2.3.4? Is any advice for this case?

Comment: the fastest way to migrate data from m1 to m2 is standalone scripts and then upload that csv to your magento 2

Comment: first take all the customer data and export it using csv and then export it in magento 2

Answer (score 0):

If you migrated using the migration tool you need to run the incremental (delta) migration command.

```
bin/magento migrate:delta [-r|--reset] [-a|--auto] {<path to config.xml>}
```

For more information on migrating changes with the migration tool check the official documentation here :

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-migrate-delta.html

Comment: Getting following error, SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4799  0-1' for key 'CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID'  FYI the table "CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID" not exits in DB.

Answer (score 0):

New orders coming to your Magento 1 during migration can be refered as Data changes and can be migrated using Magento migration tool. It's the **deltalog tables** and **triggers** that  ensures you migrate only the changes made in Magento 1 since the last time you migrated data. Check the system document: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-migrate-delta.html

As from our list of terms, we call those new orders "recent data". So here we have another options: To complete the new data updating, you can rely on our recent data migration and smart update solutions. With them you can modify exactly how you want your new data migrated.

Comment: If run "php bin/magento migrate:delta vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.3/config.xml " getting following error. SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1153 Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes. How to solve this?